# Uninitialized constant UsersController::Children

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 4 models: project, subproject, child, user:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :projects    
    end

    class Subproject < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :project
      has_many :children, :dependent => :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, :allow_destroy => true
    end

    class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
     has_many :subprojects,  dependent: :destroy
    end

    class Child < ActiveRecord::Base

    end
```

And the problem:

```
def sendinfoAll
  @user = User.all
  @children = Children.all 
  @user.each do |user|
    @children.each do |child| 
      if child.user_id == user.id
        UserMailer.welcome_email(user, child.name).deliver_now
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I want to send all users an email. But, why I can't I set @children = Children.all?

I am using Rails 4.02

Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific - what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use `Child` instead of `Children` in the below line

```
@children = Children.all #wrong

@children = Child.all #correct
```

Because You need to use ***model class name***(i.e, `Child` not `Children`) to query with the `ActiveRecord`.

Comment: @FaFa I've Updated my answer :)

Comment: @FaFa Please accept my answer as accepted by ticking it. :)